# ConcurrentHashMap and compound operations

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

Hashtable and Collections.synchronizedMap are thread safe but still compound operations like

```
if (!map_obj.containsKey(key)) {
   map_obj.put(key, value);
}
```

needs external synchronization as:

```
synchronized(map_obj) {
    if (!map_obj.containsKey(key)) {
       map_obj.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Suppose we have ConcurrentHashMap(CHM) instead of Hashtable or HashMap. CHM provides an alternative `putIfAbsent()` method for the above compound operation, thus removing the need of external synchronization.

But suppose there is no `putIfAbsent()` provided by CHM. Then can we write following code:

```
synchronized(concurrenthashmap_obj) {
    if (!concurrenthashmap_obj.containsKey(key)) {
       concurrenthashmap_obj.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I mean can we use external synchronization on CHM object?Will it work?

For above compound operation there is `putIfAbsent()` method in CHM but how can we achieve  thread safety **for other compound operations** if we are using CHM. I mean can we use external synchronization on CHM object?

Answer (score 17):

No, you cannot use external synchronization to ensure atomicity of compound operations over `ConcurrentHashMap`.

To be precise, you can use external synchronization to ensure atomicity of compound operations, but only if all operations with `ConcurrentHashMap` are synchronized over the same lock as well (though use of `ConcurrentHashMap` won't make sense in this case - you can replace it with regular `HashMap`).

Approach with external synchronization works with `Hashtable` and `Collections.synchronizedMap()` only because they guarantee that their primitive operations are `synchronized` over these objects as well. Since `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't provide such a guarantee, primitive operations may interfere with execution of your compound operations, breaking their atomicity.

However, `ConcurrentHashMap` provides number of methods that can be used to implement compound operations in optimistic manner:

- `putIfAbsent(key, value)`
- `remove(key, value)`
- `replace(key, value)`
- `replace(key, oldValue, newValue)`

You can use these operation to implement certain compound operations without explict synchronization, the same way as you would do for `AtomicReference`, etc.

Comment: your answer contradict with other answers.

Comment: But what for other compound operations for which there is no substitute like putIfAbsent() method.

Comment: Updated. You'll have to syncronize all operations over `ConcurrentHashMap` to make it work.

Comment: Appreciate the consideration of the condition where another thread is trying a basic conflicting operation on the map.

Comment: @aLearner The short version: if you're synchronizing with a ConcurrentHashMap, **You're Doing It Wrong**. The whole point of that class is that you _don't need to_ synchronize to use it; you use a different set of operations that let you avoid that sort of cost.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any reason why you can't. Traditional synchronization works with everything, there aren't special exceptions against them. ConcurrentHashMaps simply use more optimized thread-safety mechanisms, if you wish to do something more complex, falling back to traditional synchronization may actually be your only option (that and using locks).

Answer (score 6):

You can always use a `synchronized` block. The fancy collections in `java.util.concurrent` do not prohibit it, they just make it redundant for most common use cases. If you are performing a compound operation (e.g. - you want to insert two keys which must always have the same value), not only **can** you use external synchronization - you **must**.

E.g.:

```
String key1 = getKeyFromSomewhere();
String key2 = getKeyFromSomewhereElse();
String value = getValue();

// We want to put two pairs in the map - [key1, value] and [key2, value]
// and be sure that in any point in time both key1 and key2 have the same 
// value
synchronized(concurrenthashmap_obj) {
    concurrenthashmap_obj.put(key1, value);

    // without external syncronoziation, key1's value may have already been
    // overwritten from a different thread!
    concurrenthashmap_obj.put(key2, value);
}
```

Comment: answer by axtavt contradicts your answer. I want to listen your views on answer given by axtavt.

Answer (score 3):

As the ConcurrentHashMap implements the Map Interface, it does support all features every basic Map does as well. So yes: you can use it like any other map and ignore all the extra features. But then you will essentially have a slower HashMap.

The main difference between a synchronized Map and a concurrent Map is - as the name says - concurrency. Imagine you have 100 threads wanting to read from the Map, if you `synchronize` you block out 99 threads and 1 can do the work. If you use concurrency 100 threads can work **at the same time**.

Now if you think about the actual reason why you use threads, you soon come to the conclusion that you should get rid of every possible `synchronized` block that you can.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you mean by "other compound operation" and by "working". Synchronization works with ConcurrentHashMap exactly the same way as it works with any other object.

So, if you want some complex shared state change to be seen as an atomic change, then all accesses to this shared state must be synchronized, on the same lock. This lock could be the Map itself, or it could be another object.

Answer (score -1):

### About `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`

- "is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details: they do not throw ConcurrentModificationException."
- "allows concurrency among **update** operations"

### About java memory

Generally speaking the reads are safe from a synchronization standpoint but not a memory standpoint.

See also "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03304/".

So `synchronizaton` and `volatile` should be used to manage concurrent reading (vs. writing).

### About putIfAbsent

`putIfAbsent` is your [friend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate
>   it with the given
>
> ```
> value. This is equivalent to
>    if (!map.containsKey(key))
>        return map.put(key, value);
>    else
>        return map.get(key);
> ```
>
> except that the action is performed !!!atomically!!!.