# Exclusively Locking ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I know that it is not possible to lock a ConcurrentHashMap for exclusive access.
However, I cannot find why.

Is it because the "Segments" which constitue CHM aren't exposed by the api?
Presumably if they were, the client code could perform a "hand-over-hand" locking?

Cheers

Comment: Because they went to great lengths to make it concurrent? You can always synchronize it if you must.

Comment: @Jeffrey - How would one go about adding n, where n>1, elements  atomically?

Comment: @Jeffrey I assume putAll (don't have the source code before me)  iterates over the map and calls putIfAbsent for each element? If so, only the individual puts are atomic but not all the puts collectively.

Comment: @CaptainHastings Ah, you're [mostly correct](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.putAll%28java.util.Map%29).

Answer (score 2):

> I know that it is not possible to lock a ConcurrentHashMap for exclusive access. However, I cannot find why.

Simple - because it is not true. How about single instance per thread? How about synchronized methods or synchronized blocks? How about semaphore access logic?

Comment: Agree with you. We can lock a concurrent Map from exclusive access but it is not required. Use the Concurrent version of APIs instead like putIfAbsent()  etc ...

Comment: But on which object will you acquire the lock using synchronized methods and blocks? From JCIP - "The one feature offered by the synchronized Map implementations but not by ConcurrentHashMap is the ability to lock the map for exclusive access. With Hashtable and synchronizedMap, acquiring the Map lock prevents any other thread 
from accessing it."

Comment: On map object, ot any other shared lock object? If we talking about "abilities" than it is about implementation and what is under the hood - eg. synchronized maps has synchronized access methods so they are locking on themself out of the box, you don't have to implicity define synchronized methods nor blocks by yourself. I am not aware of any drawbacks for aquiring lock on any map object.

Comment: As for that, I am curious and I am digging some informations on the topic right now.

Comment: And I am correct, you can lock on CHM like on every other Object. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658335/concurrenthashmap-and-compound-operations. It is just that, it doesn't make any sense as CHM is supposed to be acces concurrently. Still you can synchronize - but you will loose all benefits of CHM - you can replace it than with HashMap as well.

Comment: I think `synchronized(map) {
        ...
    }` means having map locked for exclusive access.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive lock of concurrenthashMap can be gained using synchronizer in JAVA like Synchronizationblock, locking API

Comment: This won't be exclusive lock as other threads (from different parts of application) will be able to enter ConcurrentHashMap#get or ConcurrentHashMap#put methods as they are not synchronized. This will be illusion of exclusive lock.

Answer (score 0):

According to Goetz:

> In order to use client-side locking, you must know what lock X uses

`ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't use lock on `this` internally, instead it uses sophisticated locking mechanism, which is called Lock Stripping (locking occurs on several buckets or stripes, meaning that accessing a bucket only locks that bucket and not the entire data structure).

Moreover, the documentation of a class that supports client-side locking should explicitly state its applicability. `ConcurrentHashMap` should not be used for client-side locking because its documentation states that:

> even though all operations are thread-safe, **retrieval operations do
> not entail locking**, and there is not any support for locking the
> entire table in a way that prevents **all** access. This class is fully
> interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread
> safety but not on its synchronization details.

For instance, `ConcurrentHashMap#get` and `ConcurrentHashMap#put`  methods are not synchronized methods so if you lock `ConcurrentHashMap` object for "exclusive access" inside `Service1`, another Thread can enter `ConcurrentHashMap#put` method from `Service2` and modify internal state of `ConcurrentHashMap` object (which wouldn't happen with `Collections.synchronizedMap(..)` or `Hashtable` because all their methods are synchronized and would be locked in this case):

```
 ConcurrentHashMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap(); // will be passed into Service1 and Service2
 map.put("key", "not sold"); // initial value
```

.

```
public class Service1 {

    public void method1(ConcurrentHashMap map) { // raw use of parametrized class for brevity
        synchronized(map) { // Thread1: lock for "exclusive access"
            map.get("key"); // Thread1: expecting to get "not sold" initial value
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Service2 {

    public void method2(ConcurrentHashMap map) { // raw use of parametrized class for brevity
        // somebody forgot to lock for exclusive access
        map.put("key", "sold"); // Thread2: nothing prevents Thread2 from modifying map while Service1 gaining exclusive access because ConcurrentHashMap#put is not synchronized
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConcurrentHashMap<AType> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<AType>();

synchronized(concurrentMap){
  //do something
}
```

The above code do not work because of the fact that the lock[more than one lock to be correct(default is 16)] used by the concurrent map is not the concurrent object itself. Concurrent objects are designed to be scalable.

Java memory model guarantees works on the notion of 'happens before'.
If a lock acquired by a thread and released after, the thread which then acquires the lock sees everything earlier thread sees when it released the lock. However, this relationship only works if the same lock is used.

The above code acquire the lock associated with the concurrent map object. This is like acquiring a lock associated with any other object. However, the lock is not the same one used in the implementation of concurrent map.