# Excluding concurrent activity from a concurrent Java collection

Tags: java, concurrency, effective-java

Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, Second Edition, item 69 , states that

> [...] To provide
>   high concurrency, these implementations manage their own synchronization internally (Item 67). Therefore, **it is impossible to exclude concurrent activity from
>   a concurrent collection; locking it will have no effect** but to slow the program.

Is this last statement correct? If two threads lock the collection and perform several operations within that lock, these operations might still be interleaved?

For the statement to be correct I would expect that either these collections run threads internally with which you cannot synchronize, or they somehow "override" the standard synchronization behavior such that a statement like `synchronized(map){ ... }` behaves different than on a 'normal' object. From the answers/comments to related questions I think neither if these is true:

- [Exclusively Locking ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004059/exclusively-locking-concurrenthashmap)
- [ConcurrentHashMap and compound operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658335/concurrenthashmap-and-compound-operations)

To avoid possible misinterpretation:

- I'm aware that concurrent collections are designed exactly to avoid this global locking, my question is whether it's possible in principle
- I find Effective Java an excellent book and I'm just seeking clarity on a particular item.

Answer (score 2):

[Sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java) suggest that `ConcurrentHashMap` uses an internal mechanism for locking (`static final class  [More ...] Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock`) and does not therefore use any `synchronized` methods for it's locking mechanism.

It should therefore be simple to use the `Map` as a lock and `synchronize` on it - in the same way you could use a `new Object()` or your own `ReentrantLock`. However, **it would not affect the inner workings of the `Map`** which is - I think - what he is trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably the author indeed basically meant that  it is impossible to exclude concurrent activity from a concurrent collection **given that you don't control all access points to that collection**.

Answer (score 0):

This might clarify it (hint from another Item 67):

> It is not possible for clients to perform external synchronization on such a method because there can be no guarantee that unrelated clients will do likewise.

Your code is a client to these internally-synchronized concurrent implementations. Even if you use external lock (to slow yourself down), other clients may not and will still execute internal implementation concurrently.